# Meet import error in terminal, but PyCharm can run it

Tags: python, python-3.9

My python project is like this:

```py
- project
|
-- datasets
|
----__init__.py
|
----toy.py
|
--trainer
|
----train.py
```

In `datasets/__init__.py`:

```py
# datasets/__init__.py
from .toy import xxx
```

And I try to import functions and classes from `toy.py` in `train.py`.
So, in `train.py`, I write:

```py
import datasets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(datasets.__dict__)
```

When I issue `python trainer/train.py` in terminal, an import error occurs:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'"

But, I can run `train.py` in Pycharm by clicking the "run" button on the right corner.

Can anyone tell me why and give any advice to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pycharm adds your project directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable (you could add other folders with Settings->Project Structure->Add Content Root).

Outside of the virtual environment of pycharm your project was not set to any search path.
Two options:

1. Append project path to PYTHONPATH environment variable (either create new environment variable PYTHONPATH or add path with ";" to existing variable)
2. use sys.path.append:
   add following lines

```py
  import sys
  sys.path.append(r"../project")
```

before `import datasets` in train.py